# Site Down for few minutes after clearing cache

Tags: caching

My site is going down every time whenever I am clearing the cache. Site will works again in 5-10 minutes after refreshing web page 2-3 times.
Also I am getting 500 internal server error after clearing the cache. 
After refreshing web page 2-3 times site is working fine as before. 
Additional information as follow.

- Drupal 7
- Boost
- APC
- Apache web server

Can any one put some light on above issue.

## **Edited**

**Apache error logs**
[Tue Jul 07 08:51:12 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds, referer: xxxxxxxxx.com

[Tue Jul 07 08:51:12 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: xxxxxxxxx.com PHP Warning: Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

[Tue Jul 07 08:51:18 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 26541 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL PHP Warning: Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: HTTP 500 means "See server logs for real error message", Apache even tells you so on 500 screen if you don't configure it otherwise, so please do it and post what you find.

Comment: Error logs [Tue Jul 07 08:51:12 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds, referer: http://xxxxxxxxx.com
[Tue Jul 07 08:51:12 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://xxxxxxxxx.com
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jul 07 08:51:18 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 26541 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed "**Memcache**" module ? If no then :

First of all, check mysql slow query log. Also install "Memcache" module which will help you to reduce mysql server load.

Please refer [this link](http://www.tecmint.com/install-memcached-caching-server-on-rhel-centos-fedora/) for Drupal Memcache installation.